# PHP Upload PDF mime type is application/unknown

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I am having this problem uploading PDFs to site.

I try it on one a computer, OS X,  the mime/type is application/unknown. But when I try to upload the PDF from another mac, after sending it over by email, the mime/type is application/pdf.

What could be causing this problem?

Upload is done through PHP so I get the mime/type through $_FILE['name']['type']

Comment: What is "it"? What is your test setup? How are you uploading the PDFs?

Comment: Regular form upload, enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro forma answer since your question is too vague without any code: The mime type for file uploads is indeterminate. Browsers simply attach files in a multipart `<form>` and add a mime type on a best guess basis. What PHP sees in `$_FILES["upload"]["type"]` is not necessarily correct and could even be intentionally false.

It's best to ignore this field and instead use [mime_content_type($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) or similar methods to determine the correct content type.

Comment: Would mime_content_type also solve the problem of sometimes in windows images being image/pjpeg and not the standard image/jpeg?

Comment: Also it says mime_content_type is deprecated and replaced by Fileinfo

Comment: @Devin: Fileinfo is not quite standard, because it's seldomly used. I'm not sure either is working on Windows setups because they rely on the mime-magic database. Can't say anything to the /pjpeg issue, but if it's a progressive Jpeg the file should get the according mime type.

Comment: Btw, should `mime_content_type` not be available (or really get deprecated) then you can still use the version from http://upgradephp.berlios.de/ or http://pear.php.net/PHP_Compat